# Why is my function to change the background color run (alert works), but does not change the color?

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6, dom-events, ecmascript-5

Currently learning Javascript, complete newbie. Trying to write a function that, when a button is clicked, toggles the background color of the `<body>` element from white to purple and vice-versa.

The alert is working so the function is being run, but the color never changes.

Have absolutely no idea what's going on...

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>My Title</title>

</head>
<body>>
  <button>Click me!</button>

  <h1>I am an h1!</h1>
    <p id="first" class="special">Hello</p>
    <p class="special">Goodbye</p>
    <p>Hi Again</p>
  <p id="last">Goodbye Again</p>
  

  <!-- SCRIPS -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="exercises.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
var color_button = document.querySelector("button");
var is_purple = false;

color_button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert("clicked");
    if (is_purple = false) {
        document.querySelector("body").style.backgroundColor = "purple";
        is_purple = true;
    }
    else {
        document.querySelector("body").style.backgroundColor = "white";
        is_purple = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: use `==` or `===` instead of `=` in the `if` comparison.

Comment: Thanks everyone, it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using the single equals in your comparator. Single equals is for assigning a value to a variable, not for comparison.

```
color_button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert("clicked");
//what you had
//    if (is_purple = false) {
//what it should be
      if (is_purple === false) {
        document.querySelector("body").style.backgroundColor = "purple";
        is_purple = true;
    }
    else {
        document.querySelector("body").style.backgroundColor = "white";
        is_purple = false;
    }
});
```